# What's a Pthread?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

I'm getting confused on the idea of "pthread" and "thread". I know pthread is short form for POSIX thread, which is a type of standardized thread used in UNIX. But people often use "thread" to refer a thread. Are pthread and thread equivalent? Or pthread is only the name for threads used in UNIX?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ah that clears the concept for me. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Threads are a generic concept. [Wikipedia defines it as](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29):

> In computer science, a thread of execution is the smallest sequence of programmed instructions that can be managed independently by an operating system scheduler. A thread is a light-weight process.

Pthreads or [POSIX threads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) are one implementation of that concept used with C program on Unix.  Most modern languages have their own implementation of threads.  From that web page:

> Pthreads are defined as a set of C language programming types and procedure calls, implemented with a pthread.h header/include file and a thread library - though this library may be part of another library, such as libc, in some implementations.

Answer (score 4):

Pthreads refers to the POSIX standard (IEEE 1003.1c) defining an API for thread creation and synchronization. This is a specification for thread behavior, not an implementation. Operating-system designers may implement the specification in any way they wish. Numerous systems implement the Pthreads specification; most are UNIX-type systems, including Linux, Mac OS X, and Solaris. Although Windows doesn’t support Pthreads natively, some third- party implementations for Windows are available.

Three main thread libraries are in use today: POSIX Pthreads, Windows, and Java. Pthreads, the threads extension of the POSIX standard, may be provided as either a user-level or a kernel-level library. The Windows thread library is a kernel-level library available on Windows systems. The Java thread API allows threads to be created and managed directly in Java programs. However, because in most instances the JVM is running on top of a host operating system, the Java thread API is generally implemented using a thread library available on the host system. This means that on Windows systems, Java threads are typically implemented using the Windows API; UNIX and Linux systems often use Pthreads

Comment: I appreciate this great answer of yours.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Gray,

Pthread is POSIX complaint which means you can use it across most of the UNIX operating systems.

No need to rewrite them for each of Unix (Linxux,FreeBSD, etc) and the behavior would be same across all of them .